# How to Extract Month from a given date in MMM format in Google sheets using script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

In a column, I have a date like `3/15/2020 20:41:29`

Now how I can extract the month in `MMM` (*like Jan, Feb, Mar etc*) format.

The following I have tried but only get the month in integer and not in text form.

```
 var date = new Date("3/20/2020 20:41:29");
 var month = date.getMonth()+1;
```

but the output is `3` and **not** `Mar` (*as in March*).

How to get the month name like `Mar, Apr, Jun` etc.

Answer (score 3):

using V8 one other solution would be to do:

```
const date = new Date("3/20/2020 20:41:29");
const month = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en', { month: 'short' }).format(date)
Logger.log(month)
```

I highly recommend you have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date)

Answer (score 1):

Often you can use the Date() class constructor depending upon the string format.

```
function makeMyDate() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(Utilities.formatDate(new Date('3/15/2020 20:41:2'), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "MMM"));
}
```

[Utilities.formatDate()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatDate(Date,String,String))

[Simple Date Format](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)